# Number-theoretic proof of integrality of a fraction and asymptotics of sum over partitions related to symmetric group

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, asymptotics, partitions

Consider $\;\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)\in\mathbb{Z}_+^n\;$ such that $\;1\alpha_1+...+n\alpha_n=n.\;$ Let $\varphi$ denote Euler totient-function.

Let $\;T_\alpha\;$ be a set of permutations in $S_n\;$ of a type $[1^{\alpha_1}...n^{\alpha_n}].\;$ It's well-known that $\;\#T_\alpha=\frac{n!}{1^{\alpha_1}\cdot...\cdot n^{\alpha_n}\cdot\alpha_1!\cdot...\cdot\alpha_n!}.\;$

Obviously, $\forall\sigma\in T_\alpha\;|\{\sigma^d:\;d\in\mathbb{N}\}\cap T_\alpha|=\;\varphi(L_\alpha),\;$ where $\;L_\alpha=\min(L:\;\forall i\;(\alpha_i\neq0\;\Rightarrow\;i|L)).\;$

Let $G$ be a finite group. For $x,y\in G\;$ say, $\;(x\succeq y)\;\Leftrightarrow\;(\exists d\in\mathbb{N}: x^d=y)\;$. Say, $(x\sim y)\;\Leftrightarrow\;(x\succeq y\;\land\;y\succeq x).$

Thus, $|S_n/\sim|=\sum_\limits{\alpha\vdash n}\frac{\#T_\alpha}{\varphi(L_\alpha)}.\;$ So, I have two questions:

> 1. Are there any number-theoretic proofs of integrality of $\displaystyle\frac{\#T_\alpha}{\varphi(L_\alpha)}=\frac{n!}{1^{\alpha_1}\cdot...\cdot n^{\alpha_n}\cdot\alpha_1!\cdot...\cdot\alpha_n!\cdot\varphi(\min(L:\;\forall i\;(\alpha_i\neq0\;\Rightarrow\;i|L)))}?$

> 2. What is asymptotics of $|S_n/\sim|\;$ as $\;n\rightarrow\infty?$

I've heard, it's not good to ask questions here without trying to answer them oneself, but I have no idea how to do it. The only thing I can do is checking values of $|S_n/\sim|$ for small $n$.

Comment: Regarding the equivalence relation $\sim$: you might want to Google the keyword "power graph of a group."

Comment: By the way, another way to phrase $\sim$ (at least for finite groups $G$): $g\sim h$ if $g$ and $h$ generate the same cyclic subgroup. Hence you are asking for (an asymptotic for) the number of cyclic groups of the symmetric group.

Comment: $\varphi(L_{\alpha}) \le L_{\alpha} \le g(n)$ where $g(n)$ is OEIS [A000793](http://oeis.org/A000793), so $\frac{n!}{g(n)} \le |S_n/\sim| \le n!$. In the limit, Landau's estimate for $g$ and Stirling's approximation give $n\ln n - n - \sqrt{n \ln n} + \Theta (\ln n) \le \ln |S_n/\sim| \le n\ln n-n+\Theta (\ln n)$. Is $\ln |S_n/\sim| = n\ln n - n - O(\sqrt{n \ln n})$ a good enough asymptotic for you?

Comment: @Peter Thanks, but I'm looking for better asymptotics. Is it possible to get asymptotics of (this) sum over partitions without just a majorization?

Comment: I don't currently have a clear idea of how to do that, but applying the last sentence of the question and computing small values I've found (a) [OEIS A051625](https://oeis.org/A051625) (no given asymptotic, so possibly there isn't one in the literature); (b) for $1 \le n \le 100$ the value of $\frac{|S_n|}{|S_n/\sim|}$ seems to grow quadratically.

Comment: [Code to calculate terms and first 200 terms](https://gist.github.com/pjt33/c62f15e9536d779cb1c7507eef0d6e18). The sequence seems to have some curious arithmetic properties. Based on prime powers up to 64, I conjecture that (a) for every prime power $q=p^k$ there is a cutoff $c_q$ such that beyond the cutoff the values modulo $q$ are periodic with period $q$; (b) for every prime $p > 2$, $c_p = p - 1$; (c) for every prime $p > 2$ and integer $n \ge p$, $f(n) \equiv 2f(n \bmod p) \pmod p$.